# Regex to encode special characters in xml is having issue

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex pattern to encode all the special characters in xml response but when even any xml node has an attribute with empty string as value e.g "" I am getting issue. here is my pattern used :

`string pattern = "(?<=>)(?<content>[^>]+)(?=<)|(?<start>\")(?<content>.+?)(?<end>\")";`

Here is the the complete method used for transformation :

```
`     public static string EncodeResponseXML(string responseXML)
        {
            string pattern = "(?<=>)(?<content>[^>]+)(?=<)|(?<start>\")(?<content>.+?)(?<end>\")";
            string result = Regex.Replace(responseXML, pattern, m =>
                        m.Groups["start"].Value +
                        HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(m.Groups["content"].Value)) +
                        m.Groups["end"].Value);
            responseXML = result;
            return responseXML;
        }`
```

Here is my sample xml to be encoded:

```
<Coverage>
<Type>Terrorism</Type>
<Deductible type=\"Total\" value=\"0\"/>
<Limit type=\"Total\" value=\"\"/>
<Premium>0</Premium>
<PolicyLevelCoverage>1</PolicyLevelCoverage>
<PerClaimOrOccurrenceLimit/>
<PerClaimDeductible/>
<TermAggregateLimit>
</Coverage>
```

Encoded xml is like this :

```
<Coverage>

    <Type>Terrorism</Type>

    <Deductible type="Total" value="0"/>

    <Limit type="Total" value="&quot; /&gt;&lt;Premium&gt;0&lt;/Premium&gt;&lt;PolicyLevelCoverage&gt;1&lt;/PolicyLevelCoverage&gt;&lt;PerClaimOrOccurrenceLimit&gt;&lt;/PerClaimOrOccurrenceLimit&gt;&lt;PerClaimDeductible&gt;&lt;/PerClaimDeductible&gt;&lt;TermAggregateLimit&gt;&lt;/TermAggregateLimit&gt;
```

Here the value attribute of Limit node is blank and that's the reason it is unable to encode properly`

Comment: Your "sample XML" is not valid XML.  It's not legal XML syntax to escape the double quotes that enclose an attribute value with a backslash.  Also `TermAggregateLimit` must be terminated with a matching close tag.  Also, you seem to be decoding and encoding HTML, not XML.  (I see `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` and `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`)

Comment: @Wyck , xml mentioned is just a small portion of long xml. this is just to show where exactly the issue is happening

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew not sure why you down rated the question and answer to it. Seems standard of stack overflow is going down day by day and people are just greedy to earn points and down rate other and it has no longer remain a learning platform

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be a straightforward change as your current regex stands -

```
(?<=>)(?<content>[^>]+)(?=<)|(?<start>\")(?<content>.+?)(?<end>\")
```

you are using `+` to capture content which always looks for at least one character, if you replace it with `*` it will look for zero or more occurrences and should allow you to capture empty values

Comment: Do you mean I have replace both + characters in pattern with the *. Also its failing only when attribute contains empty string ""